# How to upload a large file to Autodesk Forge "Error 416" overlapping ranges

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I get Error 416 while uploading a large file to my bucket using "buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName/resumable" but in execution a get an error 416 with reason Overlapping ranges". Any Help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that error means what it says, i.e. that two chunks seem to cover some of the same bytes. e.g. you send one request with

```
'Content-Range': 'bytes 0-4/10', 
'Content-Length': '5'
```

and one with (so they both cover byte 4)

```
'Content-Range': 'bytes 4-8/10', 
'Content-Length': '5'
```

instead of

```
'Content-Range': 'bytes 5-9/10', 
'Content-Length': '5'
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Nagy your response fixed my problem.